# Are there specific tools are used to configure, build and install source programs?

Tags: build-process

Are there specific tools are used to configure, build and install source programs?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of different specific tools depending on the platform, language(s) and frameworks you may be using...

As almost all my development is in compiled languages on unix systems, I mostly use `make` which many people will tell you is sufficiently old these days that you shouldn't clean the patina off lest you ruin it's value at auction...